# Why is matplotlib.pyplot displaying the image even though plt.show() is not invoked?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with a segmentation algorithm from scikit-image and at some point I'd like to store the segmented image to an array object, task accomplished by executing the following piece of code:

```
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 14))
        ax.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
        ax.plot(init[:, 1], init[:, 0], '--r', lw=3) # pylint: disable=unsubscriptable-object
        ax.plot(snake[:, 1], snake[:, 0], '-b', lw=3)
        ax.set_xticks([]), ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.axis([0, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 0])

        fig.canvas.draw()
        
        #Save the segmented image into a numpy array:
        data = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
        data = data.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
        segmentedImage = resize(data, (512, 512))
```

Now, the problem is that I don't want the image to be shown, I just need to store it in `segmentedImage` variable, but instead it keeps been displayed. I can't quite figure out which particular line of code is actually displaying the image, and any effort I make to prevent matplotlib from doing it, such as disabling interactive mode, seems to be a failure, since I am not working in jupyter but in Visual Code.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib does not display the images, when you put the image creation into a function. I think, the image will be drawn at the end of the cell / execution. If it is put into a function, it will be returned and not plotted out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the savefig() method. It is available as both object oriented approach `fig.savefig(...)` or the matlab style pyplot way `plt.savefig(...)`. See the links below for details:

[matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig)

[matplotlib.pyplot.savefig](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html?highlight=savefig#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig)

Comment: Even using the `fig.savefig(...)` approach I am asked to give the function a file path to save the figure in, something I'd like to avoid

Comment: Where are you intending to save the images? Are you wanting to save the images to current working directory?

Comment: I want to store the figure resulting from the plot into `data`, and that works correctly. The problem is matplotlib is displaying the image while doing previous operation, and I would like to avoid it.